# knockout: add another binding in a custom binding init

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I want to create a custom binding as a shorthand for adding other bindings -- like a macro.

```
<div data-bind="foo: 1"></div>
```

should do the same thing as

```
<div data-bind="click: clickHandler, css: { someClass: someObservable }, ...">
</div>
```

Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foo = {
    init: function(el,val,bindings,model,context) {
        // some way to add { click: clickHandler } to bindings()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call `ko.applyBindingsToNode` from within the `init` of your binding handler like:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode({ click: someHandler, text: someText });
```

If you are applying something like a control-flow, then you would want to pass the context in the second argument.

Comment: I had to add the element as first agument but than it worked. Thanks! I wonder if this is documented somewhere. I was *so* missing this method. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jQuery in your custom binder:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foo = {
    init: function(el,val,bindings,model,context) {
        $(el).attr('data-bind', 'click: clickHandler');
    }
}
```